# How I use RegExp in my Java program?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string examples:

```
00001 1 12 123
00002 3 7 321
00003 99 23 332
00004 192 50 912
```

In a separate text file. **Numbers are separated by tabs not spaces.**

I tried to read the file and print each line if it matches a given RegExp, but I could not find the suitable RegExp for these lines.

```
private static void readFile() {
    String      fileName = "processes.lst";
    FileReader  file = null;
    String      result = "";


    try {
        file = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

        String line = null;
        String regEx = "[0-9]\t[0-9]\t[0-9]\t[0-9]";
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
            if(line.matches(regEx)) {
                result += "\n" + line;
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if(file != null)
            try {
                file.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

I ended up without any string being printed!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Programmers SE, the Q&A site for whiteboard questions, not actual programming problems. Please see the [faq] for an overview of what this site is about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `[0-9]` matches exactly one digit, but your input often has multiple digits between the TAB characters.  You need to use `[0-9]+` to match each number.  (The `+` means one or more repetitions of the previous ...)

But a simpler solution would be to use `String.split(...)` ... read the javadoc.

Comment: what if some of the numbers has (-) sign in front it how can I include those numbers?

Comment: Then you need to change the regex to match an optional minus sign on the front.  (Duh!).  But I'm not going to tell you how.  Either read a tutorial on regexes ... or follow the advice of the last sentence of my answer!  Hint: SO is **not** a place to ask other people to do your programming for you.

Answer (score 0):

use this
`String regEx = "[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]+";`

- for minimum 1 character & above
- for minimum 0 character & above

{2,3} for minimum of 2 character & maximum 3 character